# SwiftUI: View flashes briefly white

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm a beginner SwiftUI programmer and I'm encountering the following problem:

I have two Views, one loading view (Rectangle) and one web view (WKWebView).

Using those two views like this:

```
var body : some View {
    ZStack {
        WebView(self.webView)
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(self.state.isLoading ? self.loadingColor : Color.clear)
    }
    .onAppear {
        // Initialize web view etc.
        // Sets self.state.isLoading to false after some time has passed
    }
}
```

Interestingly when `self.state.isLoading` changes from `true` to `false` the UI briefly flashes white.

I don't know why this is happening, especially because the WebView definitely isn't white at the point of showing.

I tried adding a background rectangle and setting the backgroundColor of `self.webView` and `self.webView.scrollView`:

```
var body : some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        WebView(self.webView)
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(self.state.isLoading ? self.loadingColor : Color.clear)
    }
    .onAppear {
        // Initialize web view etc.
        self.webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        // Sets self.state.isLoading to false after some time has passed
    }
}
```

I expected to see a brief red screen, but it remains white.

Adding an animation to the Rectangle() transition makes the flashing go away

```
Rectangle()
    .foregroundColor(self.state.isLoading ? self.loadingColor : Color.clear)
    .animation(.easeIn)
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this may have something to do with the self.state.isLoading variable and when it changes, the whole view is reloading. Can you try instead making the isLoading a local variable in the struct (@State var isLoading: Bool = false) and then toggling the local variable instead?